# SQL recursive insert

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion, recursive-query

Some context, I have one table with three columns `date, user_id, amount` where `date` stores the date in which the costumer `user_id` made a purchase for `amount` dollars.

What I want is to make a new table with the total amount of money that the costumer has spend up to that point on a daily basis.

For example, for one particular costumer , on day one (the first row of the new table) the `total` will just be the sum of `amount`s that took place between day 0 and day 1, and for the second day it would be the sum for the period between day 0 and day 2, which it becomes:

(`total` from day 1) + sum(from day 1 to day 2).

So in general the `total` for the nth day is:

(`total` from day n-1) + sum(`amount` that took place between day n-1 and day n)

I want to know if there is a way to define this recursive structure using sql or if someone can point me in the right direction. Hopefully all this makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't `(total from day n-1) + sum(amount that took place between day n-1 and day n)` the same as `sum(amount that took place between day 0 and day n)`? Or did I miss anything in your question?

Comment: Yes, but if I want to have a row for each day in the new table (lets assume I have just 3 days) then I would have to calculate the total for day 1  three different times.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+, you would just use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       sum(amount) over (partition by user_id order by date) as running_amount
from t;
```